# How to avoid auto-generate a ".cold" symbol which causes redefined error

Tags: c, gcc, symbols

I tried to modify a part of code of a project "CRIU", whose code is in https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu. I changed some codes in `criu/pie/restorer.c`, in detail, I add some new variables in function `__export_restore_task`. However, when compiling the project, using a gcc-9 would produce an error as below.

```
In file included from criu/cr-restore.c:47:
criu/pie/restorer-blob.h:3:9: error: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [-Werror]
    3 | #define restorer_sym__export_restore_task.cold 0x47a1
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
criu/pie/restorer-blob.h:6: error: "restorer_sym__export_restore_task" redefined [-Werror]
    6 | #define restorer_sym__export_restore_task 0x2270
      | 
criu/pie/restorer-blob.h:3: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    3 | #define restorer_sym__export_restore_task.cold 0x47a1
      |
```

It seems like there is a new and unnecessary symbol `#define restorer_sym__export_restore_task.cold 0x47a1`. After removing this line I could compile the project successfully.

However, using a gcc 5.4.0 to compile the project wouldn't produce this problem, so I thought it might be the problem of gcc's version. Another reason might be something with the stack cause I added some variables while compiling the original version of the project won't have this problem. Anyway, is it possible to compile the program without `.cold` symbol even using gcc-9?

For a detail information you can refer to my pull request, https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/pull/1711

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: This is not really a C question. The file `restorer-blob.h` does not even exist in the files in the repository, so it must be generated during build. When you “changed some codes” in `criu/pie/restorer.c`, you broke something. But you have not even described the changes, let alone show the changes or show a [mre]. So there is insufficient information to diagnose what you broke.

Comment: Ok, I've given my pull request, which can reproduce this problem with a gcc-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a flag `-fno-reorder-blocks-and-partition` can solve this problem, because the flag forbid gcc to generate the hot and cold symbol.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define restorer_sym__export_restore_task.cold 0x47a1
```

means the same as

```
#define restorer_sym__export_restore_task .cold 0x47a1
```

and it defines `restorer_sym__export_restore_task` symbol. As it is defined again - you get the **warning**. You treat the warning as errors.

Change

`restorer_sym__export_restore_task.cold` to `restorer_sym__export_restore_task_cold` and it will compile fine

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it failed at CI test, so I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to avoid generate the `.cold` symbol cause I can't modify the CI test.